# Demonstrate that $(x+y)\ln \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leq x\ln x +y\ln y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, logarithms, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

I need to demonstrate this statement:

$$(x+y)\ln \ \left(\displaystyle\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leq x\ln x +y\ln y \quad \forall \ x,y \in \ ]0,+\infty[$$

I noticed that $\quad\displaystyle\frac 12x + \frac 12y \quad $is a convex linear combination but I wasn't able to use this property to prove the statement. I also figured out that:
$$x< \frac{x+y}{2}<y \quad (\text{or }y< \frac{x+y}{2}<x) \quad \text{and}$$
$$\ln x< \ln \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)< \ln y \quad (\text{or }\ln y< \ln \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)<\ln x)$$

But again I'm not able to take advantage of these facts.
This problem should be solved with only calculus and real-analysis knowledge.  Any hints, tips
or solution will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=x\ln{x}$ is a convex function because $$f''(x)=(\ln{x}+1)'=\frac{1}{x}>0.$$

Thus, by Jensen we obtain
$$\frac{x\ln{x}+y\ln{y}}{2}\geq\frac{x+y}{2}\ln\frac{x+y}{2}.$$

Comment: Of course you are right. I did not think about convexity of $x\ln x$ but only about the concavity of $\ln x$

Comment: I see also much more stronger inequality.